# Something weird happens when I try to duplicate a dragged div onto a droppable, and make that droppable clone the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm working on a project that for now consists of an openable menu that contains a draggable div. I have setup a grid with droppable, so that when I drag the div from the menu and drop it on one of the div's on the grid, the div I dropped it on clones it.

You can imagine this as grabbing an icon on your desktop, and dropping it in another place.

The problem I'm having is that when I drop the div the first time, it looks normal, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhkeU.png

But when I grab the div that was dropped and drag it to another one of the boxes, something really weird happens, like this (I continuously grabbed and dropped the div from top to bottom in that column): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rxny.png

Forgive me, I tried setting up a jsfiddle, but it doesn't quite work. When you click the bar on the left, the menu with the draggable div doesn't open. Please feel free to try to make it work! jsfiddle.net/MarcosPortugal/KWJzS/

Here is the html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Robin Blom</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- styles -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" />

  <!-- calling scripts - bootstrap&jquery -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- 

BODY 

-->
<body>

  <div class="grid-container">

  </div>


  <!-- Script in the end for faster page loading -->
  <script src="js/startpage.js"></script>
  <script>
  renderGrid();
  renderBoxMenu();
  renderTestIcon();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code (the last part, after the "jQuery for the website" comment, is the most important for this question):

```
/* Javascript file */

//Function that renders the grid used to place the icons
function renderGrid(){
    /*
    VARS USED FOR BOX SIZES (in pixels)
  */

  var box_width = 100;
  var box_height = 100;
  var box_margin = 10;  // The space between boxes
  var box_background_color = 'rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.5)';

  var user_width = $(window).width();
  var user_height = $(window).height();

    /* 
    Calculating the number of columns/rows to be drawn based on the dimensions of the user's viewport
    */

    // Number of boxes horizontally counted
    var box_horizontal_number = Math.floor( (user_width - box_margin) / (box_width + box_margin) ); 

    //Number of boxes vertically counted
    var box_vertical_number = Math.floor( (user_height - box_margin) / (box_height + box_margin) );

  /*
  Drawing the grid-container on the browser
  */
  var grid_container_string = '<div class="grid-container"></div>';

  // Printing the grid-container
  $( "body" ).append( box_string );

  // Calculating the width and height of the container
  var grid_width = ( box_horizontal_number * box_width ) + ( box_horizontal_number * box_margin );
  var grid_height = ( box_vertical_number * box_height ) + ( box_vertical_number * box_margin );

  //Adding css to the grid-container
  $( ".grid-container ").css({
    "position": 'absolute',
    "width": grid_width,
    "height": grid_height,
    "top": '50%',
    "left": '50%',
    "margin-top": -( grid_height / 2 ),
    "margin-left": -( grid_width / 2 ),
    "z-index": '-2'
  });

    /*
    Drawing the grid on the browser
    */

    var box_string = '<div class="box"></div>';

    // Printing the box div's
    for(var i = 0; i < ( box_horizontal_number * box_vertical_number ); i++) {
        $( ".grid-container" ).append( box_string );
    };

    // Adding the CSS to the box div's
    $( ".box ").css({
        "display": 'inline-block',
        "width": box_width,
        "height": box_height,
    "background-color": box_background_color,
    "border-radius": '5px',
    "margin": ( box_margin / 2 ) + 'px ' + ( box_margin / 2 ) + 'px ' + ( box_margin / 2 ) + 'px ' + ( box_margin / 2 ) + 'px',
    "z-index": '-1'

  });
}; // End of renderGrid();

// Function that renders the menu from where the icons are chosen
function renderBoxMenu(){
  /*
  VARS USED FOR THE BOX-MENU
  */
  var box_menu_width = 300;
  var box_menu_height = 500;
  var box_menu_color = "rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.7)";

  var box_menu_handle_width = 20;
  var box_menu_handle_color = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";

  /* Drawing the box-menu */
  var box_menu_string  = '<div class="box-menu"> <div class="box-menu-handle"></div> </div>';

  $( "body" ).append( box_menu_string );

  /* Adding the CSS to the box_menu and box_menu_handle */
  $( ".box-menu ").css({
    "position": 'absolute',
    "width": box_menu_width,
    "height": box_menu_height,
    "left": -(box_menu_width - box_menu_handle_width),
    "top": '50%',
    "margin-top": -( box_menu_height / 2 ),
    "background-color": box_menu_color,
    "overflow": 'hidden'    
  });
  $( ".box-menu-handle ").css({
    "position": 'relative',
    "height": box_menu_height,
    "width": box_menu_handle_width,
    "float":'right',
    "background-color": box_menu_handle_color
  });


};// End of renderBoxMenu();

// Function that renders a test icon on the icon menu
function renderTestIcon(){
  test_icon_string = '<div class="test-icon"></div>'

  $(".box-menu").append(test_icon_string);

  $(".test-icon").css({
    "width": '100px',
    "height": '100px',
    "border-radius": '5px',
    "background-color": 'blue'
  });
};

function setUnlockedMode(){};

function setLockedMode(){
  //$(".grid-container").fadeOut();
};





/* jQuery for the website */

var box_menu_state = "hidden"; // box is hidden by default
$(document).ready(function(){

  // jQuery for the box menu handle
  $(".box-menu-handle").click(function(){
    if( box_menu_state == "hidden" ){
      $(".box-menu").animate( { left: 0 }, 500 );
      box_menu_state = "visible";
      setUnlockedMode();
    }else{
      $(".box-menu").animate( { left: -( $(".box-menu").width() - $(".box-menu-handle").width() ) }, 500 );
      box_menu_state = "hidden";
      setLockedMode();
    }
  });

  //jQuery for the ... draggable stuff
  $( ".test-icon" ).draggable({
    containment: "body",
    helper: function(){
      $copy = $(this).clone();
      return $copy;
    },
    appendTo: 'body',
    scroll: false
  });

  $( ".box" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ){
      $(this).html( $(ui.draggable).clone() );
      $(this).droppable('disable');

      $( this ).draggable({
        containment: "body",
        helper: function(){
          $copy = $(this).clone();
          return $copy;
        },
        appendTo: 'body',
        scroll: false
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Please help me since I've been trying to solve this for hours and couldn't find a solution. If something isn't clear, please ask me and I will explain! Thank you so much!